# How to setup default environment quickly in Docker?

Tags: batch-file, docker, docker-machine

Currently when I do almost any docker command (e.g. `docker ps`) I get the following error message:

```
An error occurred trying to connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.23/containers/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

To solve this issue I have to run the following command:

```
@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env') DO @%i
```

Becuase I do this so often, I decided to put this is a .bat script called `setup-docker-env.bat`

However whenever I run that script I get the following error:

```
i was unexpected at this time.
```

This is odd as it works on the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In batch files replace `%` with `%%` on FOR statements

Answer (score 1):

The `%` chars need to be escaped. Your .bat file needs to have the following contents:

```
@FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i IN ('docker-machine env') DO @%%i
```

Comment: Thanks but @Gerardo Grignoli answered before you.